# Can't seem to pass options to Hammer.js Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

What am I doing wrong? Can't seem to pass any options to the JQuery plugin of Hammer.js

```
$('#my-div').hammer({direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL}).bind('pan', function(e){
    // do something
});
```

I've tried passing "direction" as string too but still no joy - Please help :-(

Answer (score 8):

If you're using the jquery.hammer plugin You can access the `Hammer.Manager` instance on the `data` object and set options.

In your case:

```
$('#my-div').data('hammer').get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
```

Answer (score -1):

From the [documentation](http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/):

> You can setup your own set of recognizers for your instance. This requires a bit more code, but it gives you more control about the gestures that are being recognized.

```
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement, myOptions);

mc.add( new Hammer.Pan({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL, threshold: 0 }) );
mc.add( new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'quadrupletap', taps: 4 }) );

mc.on("pan", handlePan);
mc.on("quadrupletap", handleTaps);
```