# changing the default threshold or locking the axis with hammer 2 (with jquery plugin)

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I am working on a web app that utilizes horizontal swipe (pan) but I am having trouble locking the axis (or changing the default threashold of 10). I dont want the element to swipe if the user simply drags down the page (the default set up seems a bit sensitive).

My code is as follows:

```
var $swipe = $('.swipe');
$swipe.hammer().on("panleft panright", function(e) {
 //code here
});
```

I have tried passing the options object in `hammer({stuff here})` but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Any help or guidance much appreciated.

A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered here [Can't seem to pass options to Hammer.js Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622150/cant-seem-to-pass-options-to-hammer-js-jquery) you have to get the options manager and then set the options throught that.

`$swipe.data('hammer').get('panleft').set({threshold: 0.1});`

Comment: Hi @char_alpha. Yes, I did see that, but I get the following error when I try it: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of null'

Comment: I think you might have to set the options on the 'pan' event, rather than the 'panleft' or 'panright' events. The documentation seems to show that only the 'pan' event has an options manager (http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-pan/)

Comment: $swipe.data('hammer').get('pan').set({threshold: 25}); success, many thanks

Comment: Threshold is in pixels, so `0.1` probably doesn't do much :-)
Also one word of caution with threshold is that it will take effect on *every pan*. So if you have an image slider with 10 images it will appear jumpy for every  slide. You may be better setting some kind of local variable to indicate 'thresholdPassed' and only execute your function when `thresholdPassed == true || Math.abs(deltaX) > 25`. Then you'll only get the slight jump on the first slide.